# Bluetooth headset audio streaming and recording same time

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I'm creating an Android app that uses a Bluetooth headset to record and stream simultaneously.

When streaming audio while recording with bluetooth headset microphone, It is streamed to a device speaker other than a Bluetooth headset.
(audio stream in webview)

I want to stream to audio with a Bluetooth headset while recording with a Bluetooth headset.

My sample code looks like this.

Connect bluetooth headset :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothScoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ANDROID Audio SCO state: " + state);
        if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "bluetooth connected.");
        }
    }
};

public void setBluetoothMic(Context context){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
    context.registerReceiver(mBluetoothScoReceiver, intentFilter);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    audioManager.setMode(audioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    audioManager.startBluetoothSco();

    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
}
```

Recording audio :

```
AudioRecord record =
            new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSize);

record.startRecording();
```

Stream audio in webview :

```
<audio controls id="myAudio">
    <source src="001.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

When audioManager.stopBluetoothSco() code run, audio is streamed to the headset.
But audioManager.startBluetoothSco() code run, audio is streamed to the device speaker.

Is it possible to stream audio to the bluetooth headset and record at the same time with the bluetooth headset?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: did you get any answer?